# P-Channel MOSFET has a really high voltage drop

Tags: mosfet, p-channel

I just got a new P-Channel MOSFET [FQP47P06](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/FQP47P06-D-1810006.pdf).  In the datasheet it says it has an RDSon of 26 milliohms, Vgs(th) of -4V, and a max current of 47A, but when I hooked it up in a simple test circuit like this:

[image]

It generated a voltage drop of 0.6V and was getting quite warm, I can't understand why it's generating such a high voltage drop when it apparently has an RDSon of 26 milliohms.  Is there something I am missing?

I also tried recreating the circuit with an IRLZ44N on the low side and removing Q1, the IRLZ44N had a voltage drop of around 0.07V. In the original circuit with the P-Channel MOSFET, I also increased the current flowing through Q1, and at 2A it generated a voltage drop of about 1.9V using a 60W car lamp.

**Edit:** I managed to measure the resistance with my multimeter and I was able to measure about 0.8 ohms constant, I was also increasing the gate voltage to above -10 volts and the resistance stayed the same.

Could it be a fake?

Could it be a fake MOSFET or is it simply that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe check again if everything is connected as in the schematic? 0.6 V sounds like a diode voltage drop rather than a conducting MOSFET.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like the drain and source are the wrong way round. Looking at figure 4, you can see that 0.6V is about right with some heating. 1.9V at 2A is surprising though

Comment: The threshold voltage of a FQP47P06 is around -3 V, you provide Vgs = 7.9 V so that should be enough. Looking at the figures in the datasheet confirms this. So either 1) that MOSFET is damaged or 2) you've connected it the wrong way and swapped Drain and Source, that 0.6 V is the forward voltage of the Drain-Bulk (shorted to Source) diode. Swap drain and source and try again.

Comment: Where did you buy them?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't swap drain and source pins? 0.6V is suspicious.

Comment: Are you using a solderless breadboard? Are you measuring on the MOSFET leads? The breadboard contact resistance can be 0.5 ohm or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded that these are fake MOSFETS because when I measured the resistance with my multimeter they gave a resistance of about 0.8 ohms and at 770mA load at 0.6V drop, the calculated resistance is 0.78 ohms. So unfortunately these seeam to be fake MOSFETs. :(

Comment: You actually might be measuring the parasitic diode inside virtually every mosfet so, you still might have misconncted your mosfet in the original circuit.

Comment: Aha, I think I have it wired correctly though because I have googled the pinout and triple-checked my connections, and also I wouldn't have been able to switch the MOSFET which I was able to. And also I purchased these of Aliexpress for about 3 dollars for 10pcs without realizing that the Digikey price for 10 units is around 22 dollars, so these are most likely fake.

Comment: OK sounds like fake. Never buy components except through dealers that are reputable in selling components. [What you might do next](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) - this link tells you about accepting one answer and, you can accept your own if you feel it is justified.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the [data sheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/308/FQP47P06-D-1810006.pdf) looks good when driving the gate with -7.9 volts: -

[image]

If the MOSFET is producing a 0.6 volts volt-drop on load then, your options as I see them are: -

- Broken device
- Wrongly connected
- Fake device
- Your load resistance is a lot lower than than 9 Ω

Answer (score 1):

Vgs(th) tells us when the MOSFET turns off, not really when it is "on." So it starts to turn on around Vgs(th), but isn't really completely on until a much higher voltage. For example, from the datasheet:

at Vgs(th) = -4 V, ID = -250 uA, and VDS = -4 V. So the resistance at Vgs(th) is \$-4V/-250\mu A = 16 \text{k}\Omega\$. Not exactly the 26 milliohms we'd expect!

So how do we get the 25 milliohms they advertise? When the datasheet says you need Vgs = -10 V to get 25 milliohms. you are at 7.5, so you are somewhere in between 16k and 25m ohms, thus the heat and voltage drop.

Comment: This is definitely not the problem. Just look at the datasheet. There is a plot for Id over vds for different vgs. A vgs of -7 V should be sufficient.

Comment: The datasheet graphs are of course just typical figures : for a FET approaching worst case (or a counterfeit) Vgs=-7V MAY not be enough ... but this is not very likely

Comment: I agree that it's not too common, but if it's hooked up OK and the device is legit, it's something that does and can happen. The datasheet also does say to use > 10V in a couple of places to be fully on - so it isn't clearly one way or the other.